# Is there a good Object Pascal mode for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, freepascal, delphi

I've been doing some Object Pascal lately, and I've been unable to find a good mode for it.  I've tried `delphi-mode` and `pascal-mode`, both of which try to help too much; when they fail to understand Object Pascal syntax, it's very difficult to force them to format the code correctly.  I've been using Geany, but I miss my Emacs.  Is there another Pascal mode I should try?

#### Edit

This is Object Pascal as implemented in Free Pascal.

Comment: Which Object Pascal exactly? Apple's? Codewarrior's? Borland's TP based one? Borland's Delphi based one? Objective Pascal as implemented by Free Pascal?

Comment: @Marco: This was tagged **delphi**, so probably the Delphi version.

Comment: I'll edit to add that it's Free Pascal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an Emacs question. From the code editor point of view, there is quite no difference between FPC in Delphi mode and Delphi.

A good one I found out (Google was our friend) is ["A Pascal mode for emacs"](http://www.nada.kth.se/~inge/MY/pascal/):

1. It knows how to indent all types of Pascal statements.
2. There are movement, killing, marking and transposing functions that know
   about procedure, sentence and expression.
3. All Pascal constructs like 'begin end', 'if then else' etc. can be inserted
   with the help of templates. This is done by two commands 'M-p' that inserts
   templates and 'M-n' that move between fields in the templates.
4. When ';' is inserted the cursor will momentarily move back to the beginning
   of the sentence that was ended by the ';'.
   If pascal-auto-newline is non-nil (default nil), ';' at the end of a line
   will do a 'RET' to insert and indent a new line.

Comment: That is, at any rate, much nicer.